# Change Woocommerce Snippet code for sale percentage

Tags: php, woocommerce

```
    // Only for WooCommerce version 3.0+ Show Saved in product page and shop

add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    $percentage = round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 ).'%';
    $percentage_txt = __(' OFF ', 'woocommerce' ).$percentage;
    $price = '<del>' . ( is_numeric( $regular_price ) ? wc_price( $regular_price ) : $regular_price ) . '</del> <ins>' . ( is_numeric( $sale_price ) ? wc_price( $sale_price ) . $percentage_txt : $sale_price . $percentage_txt ) . '</ins>';
    return $price;
}
```

This code show the percentage as OFF %  I want to change it to be % OFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 3 );
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    $percentage = round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 ).'%';
    $percentage_txt = $percentage.__(' OFF ', 'woocommerce' );
    $price = '<del>' . ( is_numeric( $regular_price ) ? wc_price( $regular_price ) : $regular_price ) . '</del> <ins>' . ( is_numeric( $sale_price ) ? wc_price( $sale_price ) . $percentage_txt : $sale_price . $percentage_txt ) . '</ins>';
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: @Eslam Samir, glad to help, please don't forget to accept my answer